# Cross domain issue due between https and http page. Ajax call failing

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cross-domain

I have a website say xyz.com. i want to make an ajax call from say(http://pqr.xyz.com) to https://abc.xyz.com. but the call is failing to execute due to cross domain problem. Is there any method to overcome this. How xan i access the page via https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make cross domain calls, you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

This means you can change the server code so that the headers shows this cross-domain call is authorized. Depending on your server language, you'll have to do something like this :

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET")
w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/x-javascript") // this one of course for json calls
```

Using JSONP instead of JSON will also mean that you'll enclose you JSON in a function call, for example

```
acceptServerAnswer({'thisis':'myjson'])
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

But my problem is that i ma using the same domain. only the sub domains are different. And the protocol is http for one and https for other. Do i have to install separate certificate for each sub domain.

Comment: When you're using different ports (http is 80 and https is 443) you're doing "cross-domain" in the eye of the browser. There is no link to the certificate problem, it's really just that browser don't accept regular ajax/json requests from one port to another one (even with same domain and same protocol) so you have to forward using a proxy or use another system (JSONP is most likely the ideal solution).

Answer (score 0):

Use a server-side proxy or JSON

http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax

Comment: Got the solution. Add Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * to .htaccess file in the server root. http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/02/04/adding-access-control-allow-origin-to-server-for-cross-domain-scripting/